# How to instruct Postfix to wait until the LDAP server is back again?

Tags: postfix, ldap, email-bounces

Sometimes, my LDAP server is not responding for a couple of seconds and when Postfix does its lookup, it bounces with an error: "Invalid user specified". Is there a way to force the lookup to be retried a few seconds later before bouncing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about just increasing the timeout for LDAP lookups?  The [ldap_table](http://www.postfix.org/ldap_table.5.html) man page has details.  The default is 10 seconds.  If it's not a timeout issue -- that is, if the LDAP server is actually rejecting connections -- maybe you could set up a local replica on the Postfix server.  Whether or not this is possible depends a lot on your environment and which server you're running.

Answer (score 1):

You could also look at NSCD in order to cache the results from LDAP.